# cannot access Docker remote registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am using docker from a Ubuntu VM. I set up an unsecure registry using the steps mentioned in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/). I can push & pull images from the registry in the host machine but I cannot access the registry from another machine in the same network.

I have done the following -

1. Edited the `/etc/default/docker` and edited the DOCKER_OPTS as follows -

   `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry cmrepo.com:5000"`
2. Restarted the VM .
3. Started the registry as follows -

   `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2`

Everything works as expected till this point . I can pull/push images into the registry.

Now how do I access the registry from another machine . I tried adding an `ip-host entry (10.216.20.14  cmrepo.com)` in the `/etc/hosts` file but it din't help. I can ping 10.216.20.14 from the remote machine but cannot access the registry.

Can someone point out what is it that I am doing wrong or need to do more?

Comment: Have you opened up tcp/5000 to external traffic in iptables on 10.216.20.14?

Comment: i did `netstat -ntlp | grep "LISTEN"` and found 5000 is open in tcp6 . I think that means tcp is runing over IPv6. Is it something that is causing problem?

Comment: I am able to telnet to cmrepo.com port 5000. It is returning `Escape character is '^]'. 
`